# Reset button is not working in filter after search

Tags: jquery, twig, reset, symfony-3.4

I couldn't reset the search character in my filter form which is built-in Symfony framework using the twig form. below are my code and different file for the filter

the input text is in index.html.twig file and my code is like this

```html
{% block filter %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="title" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{app.request.query.get('name') }}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and button are in admin.html.twig and my code is like this

```
 <div class="panel-body">
     <form method="get" id="adminFilterForm" class="form-horizontal">

           {{ block('filter')|raw }}

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="row margin-t-5" style="margin-top: 13px;">
    <div class="form-group-sm col-md-12">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" value="SEARCH">
         <button type="reset" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" id="reset">
                RESET
         </button>
          </div>
         </div>

      <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </form>
   </div>
```

I have tried using jquery by this code but couldn't point the input text file to use reset button.. console shows that the .reset is not a function

```
$("#reset").click(function {
    $("adminFilterForm").reset();
})
```

any help would be much appreciated.. thanks in advance..

Comment: `$("adminFilterForm").reset();` is not a valid selector

Comment: do you know what can be the valid selector for this?

Comment: $("#adminFilterForm").reset();

Comment: $(#adminFilterForm").reset() doesn't work. i think the problem is in {{ block('filter')|raw }} in admin.html.twig?